# Is it possible to commit remote changes in remote repos in Tower?

Tags: git, git-tower

[image: Local repo]
[image: Remote repo]

I really like the workflow for commits in Tower. However I need to do my development on a remote server for various reasons. Is it possible to use tower to make commits on that server somehow?

As you can see on the images, regardless of what I select, I only get the local changes. (on the remote called Dev, plenty of other changes are being made)

Comment: Add a new remote pointing to that development server?

Comment: Yes, I've done that, but I can't seem to track the remote changes on my local computer. Do I have to reload or something?

Comment: Are you pushing to the new remote? Local changes are found under branches -> branch name -> commits....To see the repo commits it's Remotes -> origin (remote name) -> master -> commits

Comment: I want to see the changes before they are commited, is that possible?

Comment: Before staging click on the file, in the middle under file a editor box will appear shows changes

Comment: @DaveM: I don't see any changes. The way I would guess that you do it is by marking the repo that has been changed in the left hand column and the changed files would appear in the status-tab, like they do on a local repo. But they don't.

Comment: Possible to link me to a screen shot of what your looking at?

Comment: THanks a lot for taking the time. I Updated the question.

Comment: Check this out: http://cl.ly/1h1M1c0x0O2I1X3q340K

Comment: Are those changes in a branch called "Tracks" in your local repo?

Comment: Local Branches are on top left and Remote Branches are in the middle.. That file is setting in Local Branch Tracks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Git, remote repositories are "bare" which means they don't have a working directory. Therefore, version-controlled changes can't be made in a remote repository.

Changes should only be made and committed in your local repository.